# Undefined array key "rows" in Search.tpl.php when entering "Manage Groups"

Tags: groups, search, templates

The PHP warning appears everytime when a user enters "Manage Groups" (/civicrm/group).

The full warning:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "rows" in include() (line 6 of sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%7A/7A2/7A24E297%%Search.tpl.php).
```

The line looks like.

```
<div class="crm-accordion-wrapper crm-search_builder-accordion <?php if ($this->_tpl_vars['rows'] && empty ( $this->_tpl_vars['showSearchForm'] )): ?>collapsed<?php endif; ?>">
```

and this file is compiled from CRM/Group/Form/Search.tpl where this line looks like

```
<div class="crm-accordion-wrapper crm-search_builder-accordion {if $rows and empty($showSearchForm)}collapsed{/if}">
```

I did not learn much about the rendering in CiviCRM yet so I wonder what changed and what is going on here. Could somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug and I think it's left over from before this form was ajax-ified. It doesn't cause any functional problem, but the variable should probably be removed. The idea I think was that after submitting the search form, if it found any results it would collapse the search criteria, but this page doesn't work like a normal search form anymore.

Comment: Thank you... I opened an issue for CiviCRM: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3771

Comment: Now fixed in 5.54.